# How to use api key and client id for google map in @agm/core?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

We are using agm/core package to display Google maps in our Angular application.
As per the documents available for @agm/core it takes apiKey only.

`AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
   apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
})`

However in our application we need to use the client id and signature for Google maps. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in the reference documentation of AGM the clientId is also supported in the `LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral`

https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral.html#clientId

Note that the initialization accepts `LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral` object

`static forRoot(lazyMapsAPILoaderConfig?: LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral): ModuleWithProviders`

So you can write something like

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
    clientId: 'gme-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});
```

The crypto key is not used by Google Maps JavaScript API. It is used to create digital signatures for web service requests. It never should be disclosed and you can use it only on your backend servers to create digital signatures as described in the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#client-id

Procure to not expose the crypto key in your client side code.

I hope this helps!

Comment: it was suppose to be signature instead of "crypto key" in the question. i have edited the question.

Comment: Neither signature is required for Maps JavaScript API. You protect a client ID in your support portal with allowed URLs restrictions. Signatures are used for web services requests and you calculate signatures using your crypto key, but this is nothing to see with AGM module because it is pure JavaScript API and not a web service.

Comment: Have a look at the official documentation that explains how you protect your client ID: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls