# How can I use a client ID and secret to access the Google Maps JS API, instead of an API key?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a Google Map to our app via Google's JS Maps API. I'm following [the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#maps_map_simple-javascript). I've installed `@googlemaps/js-api-loader` via yarn, and am now trying to instantiate a loader:

```js
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
const loader = new Loader({
  // ???
})
```

The problem is, the docs tell me to provide an API key in this initializer. But we don't use an API key, we use an app/client ID and secret for this project.

How am I meant to use the Google Maps JS API in this way with an ID and secret, not an API key? I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949538/google-maps-client-id-or-api-key) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668066/how-to-use-api-key-and-client-id-for-google-map-in-agm-core), but neither actually tells you to *do* it. Also, [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/apikey/maps-javascript-apikey#client-id) shows you how to use a client ID when you're using a `<script>` tag, but I would prefer to load via the yarn package.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Regarding the downvote/closevote, I don't know what other info I can provide here. You initialize the API with the `Loader`, and it's supposed to take an `apiKey` param. I want to know if I can give it a `clientID` and `secret` param instead (or something like that). That's all there is to it.

Comment: And why could you not get and use an API key?

Comment: Have you registered your URL that will be used with the map? [The Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/apikey/maps-javascript-apikey#registering-authorized-urls) suggest using  a script url such as `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID` once you have registered the url from your domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client` param is supported. https://googlemaps.github.io/js-api-loader/interfaces/loaderoptions.html#client

```js
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
const loader = new Loader({
  client
})
```

If this doesn't work, please open a bug at https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/issues/306

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct client id?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it answers my question, however in my case, my issue was that I was trying to use the Oauth2 client ID. I thought I could do this because it was on the Credentials page in Google's Maps JavaScript API interface. But I realized later that, obviously (in retrospect) you can't use the oauth-specific client ID to auth with the Maps API even though it's on the Maps API's credentials page. You need an API key (or to be a legacy Premium account with a _different_ clientID, as this answer and the comment-linked GH issue mentions). See the GH issue for more info.